javax.crypto to jakarta.crypto necessary?
e are upgrading our environment from Tomcat 7 with Java 8 to Tomcat 10 with Java 21.
I have read that javax should now be changed to jakarta
In one of our JSP pages, we have
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex,javax.crypto.Mac,javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec" %>

When we replaced
javax.crypto.Mac with jakarta.crypto.Mac
javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec with jakarta.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex,jakarta.crypto.Mac,jakarta.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec" %>

We got the following error:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

Only a type can be imported. jakarta.crypto.Mac resolves to a package
Only a type can be imported. jakarta.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec resolves to a package

We have tried using jakarta.crypto.* and jakarta.crypto.spec.* instead but still same error.
Changing back to javax.crypto.Mac and javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec, it works fine again.
I cannot find anything on jakarta.crypto
Is this an exception to the javax replace by jakarta rule?

There is no jakarta.crypto.
A lot of people think that the migration from Java EE to Jakarta EE means that every occurrence of javax needs to replaced, but that's not the case. Java SE is full of javax packages. javax.swing is an obvious one, but even java.base comes with javax.crypto and javax.net.

If you can find a package using the search box at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/23/docs/api/index.html, you don't need to change anything.
If you can find a package at
https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/, you need to change
it.
For all other occurrences you'll need to do some investigation
(but you probably don't need to change them).


It appears that the javax.crypto package is an exception to the general rule of replacing javax with jakarta. The javax.crypto package is part of Java SE (core Java platform), not Jakarta EE, which means it is not subject to the migration to the jakarta.* namespace.
In your case, the javax.crypto.Mac and javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec classes are still part of the core Java API in Java 21, so you should keep using the javax.crypto package for cryptographic functionality, even in a Tomcat 10 + Java 21 environment.
So, you can revert the import back to javax.crypto.Mac and javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec since they are not part of the Jakarta EE migration process.
